# Condicional dentro de Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Tengo 2 triggers, uno que me agrega las compras y otro que anula las compras, al agregar las compras me suma la cantidad al stock y cuando elimino la compra me resta la cantidad; esto lo hago por medio de un botón que cambia el estado de la compra de VALID a CANCELED, el problema es que después de haber anulado la compra y la quiero volver a validar el trigger me vuelve a restar en el stock y no vuelve a agregar la cantidad; es decir si la compra fue de 5 y anulo queda en 0 y vuelvo a activar y me actualiza el stock a -5. Agradezco la ayuda.

Estos son los 2 triggers:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_updStockCompra` AFTER INSERT ON `purchase_details`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE  products SET stock = stock + NEW.quantity
    WHERE products.id = NEW.product_id;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_updStockCompraAnular` AFTER UPDATE ON `purchases`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE  products p
        JOIN purchase_details di
          ON di.product_id = p.id
         AND di.purchase_id = new.id
         set p.stock = p.stock - di.quantity;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Y... cuál es tu pregunta **específica**?,

Comment: Necesitas añadir una condición adicional a tu trigger, ya que lo creas para que funcione automáticamente al Actualizar "compras". deberías de hacer que solo funcione si se actualiza Y estas en el estado correcto (Anular) en caso contrario aunque tu estado sea correcto estarás anulando (ya que la condición del trigger es un update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución colocando 2 if basado en los valores del campo status, en uno restando y en el otro sumando: dejo el código de la solución

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_updStockCompra` AFTER INSERT ON `purchase_details`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE  products SET stock = stock + NEW.quantity
    WHERE products.id = NEW.product_id;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_updStockCompraAnular` AFTER UPDATE ON `purchases`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.status = 'VALID' then 
        UPDATE  products p
        JOIN purchase_details di
          ON di.product_id = p.id
         AND di.purchase_id = new.id
         set p.stock = p.stock + di.quantity;
    END IF;
    IF new.status = 'CANCELED' then 
        UPDATE  products p
        JOIN purchase_details di
          ON di.product_id = p.id
         AND di.purchase_id = new.id
         set p.stock = p.stock - di.quantity;
    END IF;  
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```